# Winforms ListView TopItem changed event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

Is there any event that fires, when  a win form's listview top item property changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event specifically for the `TopItem` property.  However you should be able to get the same effect by caching the previous `TopItem` result and comparing it on other events which are indicators of item reordering: `Paint` and `DrawItem` for example.

```
private void WatchTopItemChanged(ListView listView, Action callOnChanged) {
  var lastTopItem = listView.TopItem;
  listView.DrawItem += delegate {
    if (lastTopItem != listView.TopItem) {
      lastTopItem = listView.TopItem;
      callOnChanged();
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need a Scroll event to detect that the TopItem might have changed.  ListView doesn't have one.  Which is probably intentional, the class contains some hacks that work around bugs in the native Windows control, hacks that use scrolling.

These hacks should however not matter much in your case since you only look for a change in the TopItem.  You'll want to override the WndProc() method so you can get the LVN_ENDSCROLL message.  This worked well although I didn't test it thoroughly.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.  Implement the TopItemChanged event.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MyListView : ListView {
    public event EventHandler TopItemChanged;

    protected virtual void OnTopItemChanged(EventArgs e) {
        var handler = TopItemChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Trap LVN_ENDSCROLL, delivered with a WM_REFLECT + WM_NOTIFY message
        if (m.Msg == 0x204e) {
            var notify = (NMHDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(NMHDR));
            if (notify.code == -181 && !this.TopItem.Equals(lastTopItem)) {
                OnTopItemChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                lastTopItem = this.TopItem;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private ListViewItem lastTopItem = null;
    private struct NMHDR {
        public IntPtr hwndFrom;
        public IntPtr idFrom;
        public int code;
    }
}
```